# Extjs DatePicker: How to enable 'Click/Select' on disabled dates using mouse click?

Tags: extjs

I'm using Extjs 4.2.5 datepicker for Rooms management, when user select a date I add it to an array and then call 'setdisableDates':

[image]

```
sender.DisabledDates.push(date); 
sender.setDisabledDates(sender.DisabledDates);
```

after user select a date it becomes disable and with css I change the background color to RED.

How can I enable click or Select on those dates that already disabled just in case the user made a mistake and want to cancel?

Thank you in advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to do so by overriding "handleDateClick":

```js
function picker.beforeInit(sender, config)
{
  config.cls='room_clndr';
  config.DisabledDates=[];
  config.disabledDaysText='חסום';
  config.handleDateClick = function(e, t){
        var me = this,
        handler = me.handler;        
        e.stopEvent();
        if(!me.disabled && t.dateValue){//<---------
            me.doCancelFocus = me.focusOnSelect === false;
            me.setValue(new Date(t.dateValue));
            delete me.doCancelFocus;
            me.fireEvent('select', me, me.value);
            if (handler) {
                handler.call(me.scope || me, me, me.value);
            }
            me.onSelect();
        }
    } 
}
```

And:

```js
function picker.select(sender, date, eOpts)
{
   if(jQuery.inArray( Ext.Date.format(date, 'd/m/Y'), sender.DisabledDates )>=0) {
      sender.DisabledDates.splice( $.inArray(Ext.Date.format(date, 'd/m/Y'), sender.DisabledDates), 1 );
      if(sender.DisabledDates.length>0) {
       sender.setDisabledDates(sender.DisabledDates);
      }
      else {
       sender.setDisabledDates([null]);
      }        
   }
   else {
    sender.DisabledDates.push(Ext.Date.format(date, 'd/m/Y'));
    sender.setDisabledDates(sender.DisabledDates);    
   } 
}
```

And here the css:

```css
.room_clndr .x-datepicker-disabled .x-datepicker-date
{
 background-color:#fe5757 !important;
 color: #fff !important; 
}
```